# How should empty details in master detail grid be displayed?

Tags: information-architecture, grid

If I hide the captions for empty information and rearrange the elements, it is harder to check for details.

If the caption is displayed, it is also confusing to read. (especially if there is another field below the empty one)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case some kind of placeholder will do just fine! Try using "n/a" or an m-dash "—" where appropriate.

In more complex layouts, where plenty of fields might be missing, you can adjust the length of the entry to hide missing fields together with their captions.